# Onload my website wont load images from gallery but when clicking slider arrows images appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Website link: https://tomspink.co.uk/portfolio-lovevelo

When clicking on the slider the images will load in, I am not sure why they don't load in on-load. I am using the owl slide: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Any help would be great! :)

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-pagination {
    text-align: center;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-pagination .owl-page {
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 6px;
    width: 6px;
    margin: 6px 4px;
    text-indent: -200%;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(17, 17, 17, .4);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .58, 1);
}

.owl-carousel .owl-pagination .owl-page.active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
            transform: scale(1.3);
}

.image-slider {
    position: relative;
}

.image-slider img {
    width: 100%;
}

.image-slider.owl-carousel .owl-prev,
.image-slider.owl-carousel .owl-next {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    transition: .2s linear;
}

.image-slider.owl-carousel .owl-prev:hover,
.image-slider.owl-carousel .owl-next:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.image-slider.owl-carousel .owl-prev {
    left: 15px;
}

.image-slider.owl-carousel .owl-next {
    right: 15px;
}

.image-slider .owl-pagination {
    margin-top: -28px;
}

.image-slider .owl-dots {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.tms-slides {
    text-align: center;
}

.tms-slides .tms-icons h2 {
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.tms-slides blockquote {
    border: 0;
    line-height: 1.8;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="module portfolio-section">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
       <div class="portfolio-content">
        <div class="gallery">
         <figure class="gallery-item">
          <div class="gallery-icon"><img src="assets/images/portfolio/LV-Intro-Artwork-1920x1280-2.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <figcaption class="gallery-caption">KWD Chartered Surveyors</figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
                                <div class="portfolio-content">
                                        <div class="image-slider owl-carousel fadeOut">
                                            <img src="assets/images/portfolio/LV-carousel-mac-wtr.jpg" alt="">
                                            <img src="assets/images/portfolio/LV-carousel-mac-gall.jpg" alt="">
                                            <img src="assets/images/portfolio/LV-carousel-mac-404.jpg" alt="">
                                            <img src="assets/images/portfolio/LV-carousel-mac-about.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
        <div class="gallery gallery-columns-2">
         <figure class="gallery-item">
          <div class="gallery-icon"><img src="assets/images/portfolio/LV-Letter-card-1920.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <figcaption class="gallery-caption">Business card</figcaption>
         </figure>
         <figure class="gallery-item">
          <div class="gallery-icon"><img src="assets/images/portfolio/LV-Business-card-1920.jpg" alt=""></div>
          <figcaption class="gallery-caption">Business Card & Letterhead</figcaption>
         </figure>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

```
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Aenean vitae bibendum erat. Maecenas lobortis libero sed pellentesque aliquam. Morbi non rhoncus nulla, volutpat bibendum sem. Vestibulum sed justo in lorem vulputate ullamcorper. Sed sollicitudin felis a mi consectetur mattis. Maecenas luctus, ex non vestibulum efficitur, neque urna faucibus justo, in porta massa magna id ex. Duis ac eleifend odio. Pellentesque id metus pharetra, lobortis massa a, porttitor nisi. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam nibh nulla, porta ac orci sit amet, accumsan porta sem. Cras pharetra, lectus et semper gravida, ligula sem posuere orci, id tincidunt risus sapien non leo. Quisque ac aliquet nisi. Nam placerat tempus leo, non dictum dui vestibulum vel.

Comment: Any code would be great :)

Comment: What isn't happening that you think should be?  It looks OK to me.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/c1815cb6d3b583f3a0f75914ef0db3b2 I get this issue on load where image doesnt load in but when you click the arrow images loads in

Comment: How do I add code into here?

Comment: Paste your code into your question, highlight it and click the `{ }` button in the toolbar. Asking better questions will get you better answers. When your get a chance your should read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I clicked the `<>` and created a snippet with the owl slider. You now can add the owl JS and your JS to create a [mcve] here using images from https://placeholder.com

Comment: I do not see a portfolio owl slider in your JS at your site.

Comment: ive linked the owl slider js file now, is that what you meant? https://gyazo.com/f993002be05d451029ad8a8ac9783278
I still have the issuse

Comment: When I open the index file locally on my mac it images work it just on the live site they do not work